# Woocommerce dynamic checkout form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a dynamic form so I can hide or show different inputs when a select changes but I don't know which JS file to use

Comment: A WooCommerce page is composed of page parts each with its own template and JavaScript file. You need to specify exactly which inputs you are working with.

Comment: @user8262086 I need to change between natural and legal person, when natural is selected it must show ID, Name and Last name. When legal is selected it must show RUC and Company Name.

Comment: This has been already answered many times on StackOverFlow… You should need to create your own javascript file as in this linked thread. Once you will have some related code, you could ask specific questions related to your code issues.